# Error while using EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx ) in C++ using openssl 1.1.0

Tags: c++, openssl, cygwin

I am trying to run/compile old code that was made in 2018 using an old OpenSSL version.

I faced so many errors, but I solved them all. Now I'm just stucking with last error on this line:

```
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx)
```

The error is here:

```
 error: ‘EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘EVP_MD_CTX_create’?
   22 |         if ( EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx ) != 1 ) { }
```

The code for that part is below:

```
#ifndef SHA256_HPP
#define SHA256_HPP

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <array>

class sha256
{
public:
    inline sha256()
        : ctx()
    {
        if ( EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, EVP_sha256(), nullptr ) != 1 ) {
            throw "EVP_DigestInit_ex() failed";
        }
    }

    inline ~sha256()
    {
        if ( EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx ) != 1 ) { }
    }

    sha256( sha256 const& ) = delete;

    sha256& operator=( sha256 const& ) = delete;

    sha256( sha256&& ) = delete;

    sha256& operator=( sha256&& ) = delete;

    inline std::array<unsigned char, 32> hash( unsigned char const* const data, int const len )
    {
        if ( EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, data, len ) != 1 ) {
            throw "EVP_DigestUpdate() failed";
        }

        std::array<unsigned char, 32> hash;
        unsigned int hash_size = sizeof( hash );

        if ( EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, hash.data(), &hash_size ) != 1 ) {
            throw "EVP_DigestFinal_ex() failed";
        }

        if ( hash_size != sizeof( hash ) ) {
            throw "unexpected hash size";
        }

        return hash;
    }

private:
    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx;
};

#endif // SHA256_HPP
```

I tried:

```
if ( EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx ) != 1 )
if ( EVP_MD_CTX_destroy (ctx ) != 1 )
```

But still, I have the same error.

Any ideas what I have to change to make it run on Openssl 1.1.0 on cygwin64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.1.0 is not that old, just a few years. Are you sure that is the correct version you are supposed to be using?  More likely, you should be using 1.0.2 instead, as `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup()` doesn't exist in 1.1.0.

One of the major changes in 1.1.0 was changing the majority of OpenSSL's structs into opaque pointers instead.  The code you showed should not work in any version, as you are passing a null `EVP_MD_CTX*` pointer to all of the `EVP_Digest...()` functions, which will not work.

The code likely looked more like this originally, before you mucked around with it:

```
class sha256
{
public:
    inline sha256()
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&ctx); // <-- init with this

        if ( EVP_DigestInit_ex(&ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- use '&' here
            ...
        }
    }

    inline ~sha256()
    {
        if ( EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&ctx) != 1 ) { } // <-- use '&' here
    }

    ...

    inline std::array<unsigned char, 32> hash( unsigned char const* const data, int const len )
    {
        if ( EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- use '&' here
            ...
        }

        ...

        if ( EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- use '&' here
            ...
        }

        ...
    }

private:
    EVP_MD_CTX ctx; // <-- no '*' here
};
```

In OpenSSL 1.1.0, that would look like this instead:

```
class sha256
{
public:
    inline sha256()
    {
        ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new(); // <-- init with this
        if ( !ctx ) {
            ...
        }

        if ( EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- no '&' here
            ...
        }
    }

    inline ~sha256()
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx); // <-- no '&' here
    }

    ...

    inline std::array<unsigned char, 32> hash( unsigned char const* const data, int const len )
    {
        if ( EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- no '&' here
            ...
        }

        ...

        if ( EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, ...) != 1 ) { // <-- no '&' here
            ...
        }

        ...
    }

private:
    EVP_MD_CTX *ctx; // <-- use '*' here
};
```